# CSS: How can I show where a margin edge is to the user on a box-model

Tags: css

Consider the following:

[image]

I am writing a debug class to show the position of elements on a page. I want to show the margin edge above (outside dashed line), but realise I can not use the border as this is the inside margin edge. How can I do this?

Comment: So why don't use padding insted and use border then?

Comment: I am writing a debug class, so accurately want to show the user where the element margin is on the page

Comment: @alias51: Wrap it with another element and give that element a border.

Answer (score 5):

You’re probably best off setting an `outline` in combination with an `outline-offset`. `outline` is like border, but doesn’t take up any space in the layout and has a slightly different set of rules. Given a `div` with a 1px border and 10px margin, you’d add an outline like this:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  outline-offset: 10px;
}
```

More info on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset

Unfortunately `outline-offset` isn’t supported in IE. If you need to support that then you’ll have to go down the psuedoelement route as per the other answers.

Comment: CSS is full of stuff you never use in the day-to-day if you go digging :)

Answer (score 1):

The box model prevents this.

As you in your original post the margin of a box is not included in it's content size. Without changing your `margin` to `padding` this could only be done with pseudo elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fcwkw/1/

Since you mentioned it's a class you can simply get a div's margin with some Javascript and set the pseudo padding to the margin.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how border's work, and your image is a perfect example of that. You could create a border with a second element or with the use of `:after` for example...

Answer (score 0):

You can use :before/:after with position:absolute, border-left/right and height:100%